# How to get data of current user form firebase?

Tags: arrays, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Im using at the moment a list like this
`

This is this collection
[image]

So the problem that I have is that the name dont getting updated when user changed it in "meinprofilsettings" collection which is the main collection. .

I need the username field  of this collection
[image]

Heres how im using it now

```
      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    final user = Provider.of<Userforid>(context);
    File _pickedImage;

    return Container(
      height: 50,
      width: widget._width,
      child: StreamBuilder<List<ConversationSnippet>>(
        stream: DatbaseService.instance.getUserConversations(user.uid),
        builder: (_context, AsyncSnapshot _snapshot) {
          if (!_snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
            var _data = _snapshot.data;
            if (_data != null) {
              _data.removeWhere((_c) {
                return _c.timestamp == null;
              });

              return ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: _data.length,
                itemBuilder: (_context, _index) {
                  print(allids.length);
                  return StreamBuilder(
                      stream: firestore
                          .collection('meinprofilsettings')
                          .doc(_data[_index].uid)
                          .snapshots(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        log('data: ${_data[_index].uid}');
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          dynamic video =
                              snapshot.data != null ? snapshot.data.data() : {};
                          print(video.length);
                       return Text(video['username']);
                        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return const Text('No data avaible right now');
                        } else {
                          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                        }
                      });
                },
              );
            } else {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 250, 0, 0),
                child: Text(
                  "No Conversations Yet",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                ),
              );
            }
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Ans this is the error now

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<DocumentSnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot>>#5aafa):
Supported [field] types are [String] and [FieldPath]
'package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart':
Failed assertion: line 69 pos 12: 'field is String || field is FieldPath'


The relevant error-causing widget was
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>
lib/chatmessenger/recent_conversations_page.dart:77
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#2      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get
package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/…/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:69
#3      DocumentSnapshot.get
package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:45
#4      DocumentSnapshot.[]
package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:52
#5      _RecentConversationspageState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
lib/chatmessenger/recent_conversations_page.dart:123
#6      StreamBuilder.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/async.dart:545
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Lists` are the `Array` in dart.

You can check if a List contains a value with:

```dart
allVideoHastags.contains('some hashtag')
```

But that is not the reason for your error!

As the error says you just want to query a firebase collection with to much values. The `whereIn` clause supports a maximum of 10 values and your `allVideoHastags` has more than 10.

I would recommend that you ensure that you only send 10 elements to the filter with:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext 
   

    ....

             return  ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: _data.length,
                itemBuilder: (_context, _index) {
                  return StreamBuilder(
                      stream: firestore
                          .collection('meinprofilsettings')
                          .where(_data[_index].uid,
                              whereIn: allVideoHastags.take(10))
                          .snapshots(),
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
.....
```

That also means you would filter on the firebase side with the 10 elements and I would recommend that you filter with the rest of the elements on the client side.

If you want to get just a single user you can get the snaphost just for the path to that single id like this:

```dart
return  ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: _data.length,
                itemBuilder: (_context, _index) {
                  return StreamBuilder(
                      stream: firestore
                          .collection('meinprofilsettings')
                          .doc(_data[_index].uid)
                          .snapshots(),
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

                    String username='';

                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        username= snapshot.data['username'];
                    }
```

Take care that a `DocumentSnaphost` is not the same as `QuerySnaphot` and that it has different API.

Comment: yeah but how can i fix this ?

Comment: Why I cannot use instead of that aryraycontains is there also the limit of 10 elements?

Comment: Can you explain how to you want to use the `contains`? Do you want to download all the data and filter localy?

Comment: .snahsots ist defined for the type doc or im wrong ? I need a collection to use snapshots or im wrong ?

Comment: I don't see that you use the `conversations` collection enywhere in you code snippets. Could it be that we don't understand you because that has to be added somewhere?

Comment: I solved it by using firestore
                          .collection('meinprofilsettings')where(_data[_index].uid).snapshots. And this works but im not sure if I can use this or will this be a problem in future for any reason ?

Comment: With that you probably get for each element in your list all `meinprofilsettings`. It would blow up your firestore billing.

Comment: I updated my code so you can see a bit more of the widget and also the stream . Now it should be clear

Comment: I still think that this is a good fit for you: `firestore
                          .collection('meinprofilsettings')
                          .doc(_data[_index].uid)
                          .snapshots()` did you try it with that?

Comment: When I use firestore
                          .collection('meinprofilsettings')
                          .doc(_data[_index].uid),snapshots it says The argument type Class 'DocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'docs'.
Receiver: Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'
Tried calling: docs

Comment: the error throws here   DocumentSnapshot video = snapshot.data.docs[_index];

Comment: The errors you se with the solution is correct. You can't use `docs` on a `DocumentSnapshot` because it represents only a single document and not more of them. The get the data from a `DocumentSnaphost` just call it like this `snapshot.data['username']` as shown in the answer.

Comment: its not working I update my post so you can see how im using it

Comment: it The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Map<String, dynamic> Function()'.
Try defining the operator '[]'it says  and when I add this () it says again Class 'DocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'docs'.
Receiver: Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'
Tried calling: docs

Comment: Can you show me the whole file with the error when you use my solution with `DocumentSnapshot`?

Comment: if you mean how my code looks when I use your solution then please check I updated it already check the last post

Comment: Sorry didn't see that. Could you pls change this `DocumentSnapshot video = snapshot.data.docs[_index];` to this `DocumentSnapshot video = snapshot.data.data();`

Comment: ok and then use the it like this  video.data()["username"] or this video.data["username"]. When using the second it says The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Map<String, dynamic> Function()'.
Try defining the operator '[]' The first I will try out now

Comment: the first it says type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentSnapshot'

Comment: when using this video['username'] again the same error type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentSnapshot'

Comment: You should be able to get the data with `video['username']`

Comment: check out my last comment

Comment: Can you update again the Question with your latest code

Comment: Could you try it with this `DocumentSnapshot video = docSnapshot.data != null ?snapshot.data.data(): new HashMap<String, dynamic>();`

Comment: it give this Undefined name 'docSnapshot'.   and this  The name 'HashMap' isn't a class.

Comment: Let's try this: `DocumentSnapshot video = snapshot.data != null ?snapshot.data.data(): {};`

Comment: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentSnapshot'
The relevant error-causing widget was
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>
lib/chatmessenger/recent_conversations_page.dart:76.  this getting  really sad

Comment: Ah why didn't I see that. This is it: `dynamic video = snapshot.data != null ?snapshot.data.data(): {};` The data is ofcourse not a Snapshot anymore

Comment: ok that solved it but this error is here and when removing the dynamic video it stills says this Supported [field] types are [String] and [FieldPath]
'package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart':
Failed assertion: line 69 pos 12: 'field is String || field is FieldPath'

The relevant error-causing widget was
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>
lib/chatmessenger/recent_conversations_page.dart:76.

Comment: Can you show me what line of code that is?

Comment: you you mean 76 ? Then thats the streambuilder

Comment: That sounds like `_data[_index].uid` is not a String. Could you log that value and see what it is? Or the error is deeper in the code. Could you replace the ListTile with a simple Text showing the username.

Comment: when I printed the username and ti still shows me the usernames from the conversation collection and not the current user names I replaced the list tile with this return Text(video['username']);

Comment: And when debugging the code the uid field is a string(_OneByteString)

Comment: and logging like this   log('data: $_data[_index].uid'); give me this [log] data: [Instance of 'ConversationSnippet', Instance of 'ConversationSnippet', Instance of 'ConversationSnippet', Instance of 'ConversationSnippet'][_index].uid

Comment: You need to log it like this `log('data: ${_data[_index].uid')};`

Comment: ah then it give me this[log] data: b1Fd5KiKsyWaSWlGi4bKkkSsTYX2
[log] data: ehLe6KbwsjVucXP4imZpsmULZMw1
[log] data: Fp3unLwcl2SGVh4MbUPiRVAylYV2
[log] data: Xs0Nx8IwUJSd8YISmDxVTGD3Lcf1

Comment: That looks good. Do you still have an error or just wrong data shown?

Comment: When I use the list tile I get again the error this error The following assertion was thrown building StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<DocumentSnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot>>#5aafa):
Supported [field] types are [String] and [FieldPath]
'package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart':
Failed assertion: line 69 pos 12: 'field is String || field is FieldPath'

Comment: And the data is as you know wrong but can't check if its also in the  list tile wrong because of the error but I think so

Comment: Is it possible that I connect to you with Teamviewer or AnyDesk and I check it. It would make it much faster. I would have time ine 3-4 h. I can give you my email where you can send the data. huber.tarik@gmail.com

Comment: Hmm beter not im sorry maybe it will be faster but I dont know you .... So please lets just try to finished this this way you can tell me when you have time and then I can like trying and directly giving feedback?

Comment: No problem. I understand your decision. We will fix it step by step. First thing to clear for me. If you remove the `ListTile` and return only the `Text(video['username']);` you don't have any error?

Comment: correct and thanks for your understanding only the data is not correct

Comment: Let's then fix first the data and continue on to add the `ListTile` again. What data should be there and could you pls add again the screenshots for all collections you load. Or maybe I saw them on another question from you. But it would mak ti easier to have them here to.

Comment: OK. You say that you need the `name` field form the `meinprofilsettings` collection but from the screenshot I can't se a `name` field in that collection.

Comment: username sorry my fault

Comment: OK. When you use only `Text()` and not the ListTile what data do you see and what data should be there instead.

Comment: what I see is still the data  which saved in conversation sub collection so im using this video['username'] and that should show me the username of meinprofilsettings collection for this user.  But instead of that it show me the name field value from conversation collection for this user

Comment: Can you pls update the question to show the code you currently have with the Text

Comment: check out please

Comment: Did you check if the `username` in `meinprofilsettings` is different from the `name` in `Conversations`?

Comment: Can you double check that. When I see the code I can't imagine how data from the `Conversations` collection could end up in the part we edited.

Comment: you now 100 percent understand why im so confused l. but porbably I found something when im fullname it shows me the correct fullname but username does not work

Comment: ok wait it works now 100 percent sorry my mistake

Comment: Can we make the next problem tomorrow. Or it would even be better that you make the next one under another question.

Comment: Sure I will send you the link here then im suing for that also another account dont care about it . Maybe then you can help me with another problem but lets see first this one thank tarik for your help until now

Comment: You are welcome. I know how frustrating this can get. Try to take a rest and continue later with it. You can't belive how much that helps.

Comment: Heres the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67273720/why-im-getting-this-error-platform-interface-src-platform-interface-platform-inProbably I found something the error is also aways when im removing the fsecond streambuilder then it just show me the data as before maybe theres the problem that im using 2 streams under each other . And actually you're right hope also I found a solution for my other problem .

Comment: Heys Tarik I solved the problem it was this _data[_index].url so instead of that I was using snapshot[_index].uid. Yes thanks men . But probably you can help me now with the other problem . I will send you the link will be happy if you do .Thanks again thousand times

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67272244/how-to-pick-video-from-videoscollction-correcttly

Comment: Do you check it ?

Comment: Hi. Sorry for my late response. I'm very happy you could resolve your Problem. Let me check the other one.